# Insulation with multiple polyester layers instead of one

Tags: insulation

I am getting 3cm thickness polyester sheets for free and while it could be great not having to buy insulation myself, I wonder is it a good idea to insulate it with multiple layers of these sheets for walls (I want to do 10cm thickness insulation).

Would I lose R value by doing so, or it doesn't really affect thermal insulation of the walls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you make sure that the sheets are packed or glued together so there are no air gaps then the insulation value will be based on the material and its thickness. If you allow the sheets to flop apart then the insulation value is not so good.

Having 10cm thickness is good - when we built we put 30cm - insulation material is cheaper than 50 years of heating (or cooling) costs.

Comment: In some cases multiple sheets are better. Stagger the seams and then there is no chance for air movement +